# Downloading remote branches using Gerrit

Tags: git, gerrit

With an usual git repository, I download a remote branch with:

```
git checkout -b branch_name origin/branch_name
```

However, neither of the commands below work with a Gerrit server:

```
git checkout -b branch_name gerrit/branch_name
git checkout -b branch_name gerrit/refs/heads/branch_name
```

Error message:

> fatal: git checkout: updating paths is incompatible with switching
>   branches. Did you intend to checkout 'gerrit/branch_name' which can
>   not be resolved as commit?

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Note that `git checkout` doesn't download anything.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I manually created a gerrit remote copying the origin one I already had in .git/config, but only updated the "url" attribute, not the "fetch" one. I had:

```
[remote "origin"]
  fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
  url = remote1_url
[remote "gerrit"]
  fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
  url = remote2_url
```

Updating the fetch attribute to "+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/gerrit/*" in the gerrit remote fixed the problem.